# How to tell if a function is called within a vfork()'ed process?

Tags: c, linux, vfork

I have an interposer library for C. It is not possible to interpose `vfork()` because `vfork()` (interposing function) cannot return to the calling function after having called the real `vfork()`. But I am interposing `_exit()` because I need to know when the process finishes. And of course I am interposing `exec*()` functions. My problem is that when interposing `_exit()` there are certain things that I want to do when `_exit()` is called by a normal process but not when the process is the restricted `vfork()`'ed process.

How can I tell in a C program when my process is the `vfork()`'ed process and when I do not have access to the process id returned by `vfork()`?

**Interposer library:**

```
/* COMPILE: gcc -shared -ldl -fPIC -o libso_interposer.so so_interposer.c -std=c99 */
/* RUN:     LD_PRELOAD=./libso_interposer.so so_interposer_test */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static void (*_exit_R)(int) = (void *) 0;
static pid_t (*fork_R)(void) = (void *) 0;
static void teardown_interposer() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Destructing so_interposer.\n");
    /* Concurrency protected code to be executed only once
     * when the process finishes! */
    /* Must not be executed if/when vfork() process finishes. */
}

pid_t fork(void) {
    *(pid_t **) (&fork_R) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fork");
    /* Code to prepare for a new process.
    * More preparation in exec* interposing functions.*/
    pid_t pid = fork_R();
    return pid;
}
__attribute__((noreturn)) void _exit(int status) {
    *(void **) (&_exit_R) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "_exit");
    fprintf(stderr, "Process '%lld' called _exit(%i).\n", (signed long long int) getpid(), status);
    teardown_interposer();
    _exit_R(status);
}
```

**Testing binary:**

```
/* COMPILE: gcc -std=c99 -D FORK=vfork -o so_interposer_test so_interposer_test.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#if !defined(FORK)
#error "Define FORK: 'fork' or 'vfork'!"
#endif
int main(void) {
    pid_t pid = FORK();
    if(pid == 0) {
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if(pid > 0) {
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`vfork()` cannot return to the calling function"? Of course [`vfork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) returns. Perhaps you're thinking about the `exec` family of functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly, but `vfork()` will return 0 for the child process, just like `fork()`.

Comment: When interposing, I replace vfork() with my own function which then calls the real vfork() (in libc). Once my function calls vfork(), it cannot return to the calling function anymore.

Comment: *Why* can't your function return? What are you *really* doing? Can you create a [mcve] to show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had the same question but [the `vfork()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) says "The child must not return from the current function". So I assume the question here is about how to handle this in the child process (though it certainly needs clarification).

Comment: Does your own function have to forward to the real `vfork()`? Can you just forward to `fork()` or something that has fewer restrictions than the real `vfork()`?

Comment: @Cornstalks I have to use real vfork() for performance reasons.

Comment: You can get around the "can't return in the child" problem for vfork by having your interposer tail-call the real vfork (so it returns directly to the caller).  May involve writing asm code for the interposer, and means nothing can be done after the call, but should be doable.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Any examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

For a sufficiently recent version of gcc, you should be able to wrap vfork as:

```
typedef pid_t (*vfork_t)(void);
extern vfork_t wrap_vfork();

pid_t vfork(void) {
    vfork_t f = wrap_vfork();
    return f();
}
```

where `wrap_vfork` does all your vfork wrapping work, and returns a pointer to the real vfork (without calling it).  Gcc 6.3.0 (-O3) compiles this as:

```
    .globl  vfork
    .type   vfork, @function
vfork:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    wrap_vfork
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp     *%rax
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
    .size   vfork, .-vfork
```

The important thing to note is that it jumps directly to the actual vfork function rather than calling it, so does not itself need to return (the real vfork will return directly to this function's caller)

If you're not comfortable relying on the compiler to do the tail-call optimization for you, you can write this one small routine in asm directly rather than in C.

Comment: This would work but only if and when the compiler supports tail call optimisation. And even then, I cannot explicitly ask for it. Instead the compiler optimises my code if it feels it should. If GCC had a feature to implement a tail call at the request of the programmer (not depending on whether it is an optimisation), this would be an alternative solution to the problem.